# Laravel require indirect relationship existence

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

This is the schema:

```
Owner N->N Property N->N Resident
```

I want to load all persons which has at least a property which has at least a resident.

*Plus*: Single query, without using pre-query + `whereIn(..)` or similar

*Plus plus*: Maybe Laravel Eloquent has some appropriate prebuilt filter like `->has()` or or `->whereHas()` or similar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dot notation.

```
Owner::has('properties.residents')->get();
```